# Rails: Add request headers to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, haml, cors

**The code:** I got the following piece of code in some HAML file.

```
= image_tag "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_image.jpg"
```

It sends a request to s3 and loads the image in the browser. I got the following CORS configuration on the bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>https://www.my_site.com</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>

 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**The problerm:**
In order to be able to manipulate the images on client side, the images are supposed to be served with the following headers:

```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.my_site.com
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

but this does not happen.

**The cause:** My browser does not send 'Origin' request header, and therefore s3 does not respond with the desired headers.

**Why I think that missing "Origin" header is the cause:**
Because the response of:

```
wget  --server-response --header "Origin:https://www.my_site.com" "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_image.jpg"
```

is the following:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  x-amz-id-2: kQV8HEChV1...QHmHC1Gt/
  x-amz-request-id: A626...4A2
  Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2013 10:10:38 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.my_site.com
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
  ...
```

i.e. the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' are present.

**The supposed solution:**

Is there a way to add manually the desired headers to the image_tag in the HAML file? Something like:

```
= image_tag "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_image.jpg", :headers=>["Origin"]
```

Comment: I'm having the exactly same issue. How did you manage that? Any solution? By the way, mine is working in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no explicit way to request certain headers. I've tried to load the images via javascript, but the browser does not allow to set that particular header ('Origin'), because of obvious security issues. We solved that problem with some server-side script, but I wasn't the person with the solution, so I got no implementation details (I can check the codebase, if you insist).

Answer (score 2):

Not using image_tag, no.  Remember all image_tag does is generate the  HTML tag.  The end user's browser is responsible for loading the image source and displaying it.  Unless I've missed something major, there isn't any way for you to tell the browser to pass additional headers via HTML.

You might be able to change your method and load those images using Javascript.  Maybe you can pass headers that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check [How to debug CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413763/how-to-debug-cors-error) for a solution.

I spent a lot of time thinking the problem was server side but finally it was due to a browser issue.

You can force Chrome to user the proper CORS protocol by loading your image through JavaScript.
Try changing your html to an empty img tag and loading your image into it. Like:

```
<span id="source-url" class="hidden"><%= @product.images.first.attachment.url(:large) %></span>
```

`<img id="art-image">`

and in a .js file

```
artImage = document.getElementById('art-image');
$(artImage).attr('crossOrigin', '');
$(artImage).attr("src", $("#source-url").text());
$(artImage).one('load', function() {
  // image processing
});
```

Hope it helps!